# Independence of operator*vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> Let $X,Y$ are linear spaces and $A$ a linear operator from $X$ to $Y$.
>   Is that true that if $\{x_1 ,\dots, x_n\}$ is a linearly independent
>   subset of $D(A)$ (domain), then $\{Ax_1 ,\dots, Ax_n\}$ is linearly
>   independent?

My proof:

\begin{align}
a_1  x_1+\dots +a_n  x_n &= 0\\
A(a_1  x_1+\dots +a_n  x_n) &= 0 \\
a_1  Ax_1+\dots +a_n  Ax_n &= 0 \\
a_1 = \dots = a_n &= 0.
\end{align}

Then  $\{Ax_1 ,\dots, Ax_n\}$ is linearly independent.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement is clearly false. Take $A : \mathbb{R}^3 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 $ such that $A(x, y, z) = (x, y)$. Then $A(1, 0, 0) = A(1, 0, 1) = (1, 0)$. Here, $(1, 0, 0)$ and $(1, 0, 1)$ are linearly independent, but their images not, since they coincide.

The problem in your proof is that you can't conclude $a_1 = \dots = a_n = 0$ from $a_1 Ax_1 + \dots + a_n Ax_n = 0$ in general. Note that the statement would become true if you assume $A$ to be injective.